# Error in Testing the User Controller: User count did not change by 1 and Expected response to be a redirect

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

These are the errors it shows, however, it does work on the system:

```
UsersControllerTest#test_should_destroy_user [/mnt/c/code/toy_application/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:42]:
"User.count" didn't change by -1.
Expected: 1
  Actual: 2

Failure:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_destroy_user [/mnt/c/code/toy_application/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:42]:
"User.count" didn't change by -1.
Expected: 1
  Actual: 2

Failure:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_edit [/mnt/c/code/toy_application/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:33]:
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/login>
Response body: <html><body>You are being <a href="http://www.example.com/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>


UsersControllerTest#test_should_update_user [/mnt/c/code/toy_application/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:38]:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/775686554> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/login>.
Expected "http://www.example.com/users/775686554" to be === "http://www.example.com/login".
```

**user_controller.test**

```
require "test_helper"

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = users(:manon)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get users_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get signup_path
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create user" do
    assert_difference("User.count") do
      post users_url, params: { user: { email: "user@example.com", name: "Example User", password: "thisfoobar", password_confirmation:"thisfoobar"} }
    end

    assert_redirected_to user_url(User.last)
  end

  test "should show user" do
    get user_url(@user)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get edit_user_url(@user)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update user" do
    patch user_url(@user), params: { user: { email: @user.email, name: @user.name, password: "thisfoobar", password_confirmation: "thisfoobar"  } }
    assert_redirected_to user_url(@user)
  end

  test "should destroy user" do
    assert_difference("User.count", -1) do
      delete user_url(@user)
    end

    assert_redirected_to users_url
  end

end
```

user_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index,:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

  # GET /users or /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1 or /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # debugger
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users or /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        log_in @user
        format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice: "Welcome to the Sample App" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # def update
  #   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  #   if @user.update(user_params)
  #     # Handle a successful update.
  #   else
  #     render 'edit'
  #   end
  # end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1 or /users/1.json
  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile Updated"
      redirect_to user_url(@user)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "There was an error updating your profile."
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1 or /users/1.json
  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end
  

  #show micropost for the user
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = @user.microposts.first
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters
# Confirms a logged-in user.
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  # Confirms an admin user.
  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :microposts
    attr_accessor :remember_token
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
    uniqueness: true
    
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

    # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
    def User.digest(string)
        cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
        BCrypt::Engine.cost
        BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
    end

    # Returns a random token for the advanced login(remember me functionality).
    def User.new_token
        SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
    def remember
        self.remember_token = User.new_token
        update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
    end

    # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
    def authenticated?(remember_token)
        return false if remember_digest.nil?
        BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
    end

    # Forgets a user.
    def forget
        update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
    end
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.2.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4", ">= 7.0.4.2"

#bootstrap
gem "bootstrap", "~> 5.2.0"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

What does the error mean and how do I fix the error?

Comment: The problem here is that editing and deleting require the user to be signed in and you're not actually signing the user in. Remeber that the tests don't run sequentially and the session is not maintained across tests. You could either sign the user in by sending a POST request to your sessions  controller or you can provide a method which lets you stub out your authentication system to sign a user in directly.

Comment: @max I'm a beginner on this as I'm only following the Michael Hart tutorial. How would I do the POST request on the session controllers?

Comment: I was guessing that its Hartl's book. Isn't it covered in the book? Its behind a paywall now so I can't actually see what route is used.

Comment: @max yeah but I have run into some errors with it. I went through the codes and I don't think I have missed anything

Comment: You should be able to write a test helper that looks something `def login_as(user); post sessions_path, params: { email: user.email, password: user_password }; end`. I'm not a huge fan of that book and especially not the auth system which is pretty terrible.

Comment: @max do you know any articles about the kind of test helpers?